# eval() function not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
node set like \\ node="javascript:%20openFolder(4);refreshSplashScreen();setModuleName(adHocTitle);"
var hrefUri = node.href.trim();
hrefUri = hrefUri.ltrim("javascript:");

eval(hrefUri);
```

eval(hrefUri) work in google chrome,IE,etc but not working in Firefox.
if any one has solution than please suggest me.
Thank you.

Comment: Tip: Someone once said: _"If you need to use `eval()` in your code, it's likely that your code has something wrong with it"_.

Comment: Well you have %20 in that string...trim is not going to remove that

Comment: this %20 included after swap one jsp to another jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try

```
<script>
  eval('javascript:%20alert()');
  </script>
```

not work but

```
<script>
      eval('javascript:alert()');
      </script>
```

working ok please remove %20